# Count number of connected regions/meshes

Tags: image-processing, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to count number of connected region. For ex I have a region below which has 2 connected region. 
And also, How to check whether the function `RegionDifference[]` return empty region

[image]

But how can I count computationally with Mathematica ? Is there a function performs automatically ?

```
V = {{1454.16552734375`, 942.5`}, {337.9480285644531`, 
    407.9453125`}, {318.0152587890625`, 
    428.353515625`}, {342.0124816894531`, 
    403.962646484375`}, {277.94842529296875`, 
    486.03125`}, {1198.7965087890625`, 
    1234.8741455078125`}, {312.4529724121094`, 
    434.356689453125`}, {1142.8619384765625`, 
    1274.6539916992188`}, {1216.492431640625`, 
    1218.9954833984375`}, {1179.011962890625`, 
    1250.852294921875`}, {688.2337646484375`, 
    1314.6601257324219`}, {733.9116821289062`, 
    1330.8984069824219`}, {627.462158203125`, 
    1283.3348999023438`}, {583.695556640625`, 
    1239.4417114257812`}, {1511.9337158203125`, 
    652.8341674804688`}, {1511.9337158203125`, 
    642.1658325195312`}, {651.5089721679688`, 
    1299.1900024414062`}, {1272.906494140625`, 
    1154.5545959472656`}, {1085.2890625`, 
    1306.9449462890625`}, {599.6814575195312`, 
    1258.9429016113281`}, {272.437255859375`, 
    539.4434814453125`}, {287.7309265136719`, 
    461.513427734375`}, {608.1034545898438`, 
    1267.4883422851562`}, {268.2161865234375`, 
    663.7935180664062`}, {1156.6552734375`, 
    397.2230224609375`}, {763.6713256835938`, 
    1335.1801147460938`}, {310.9466857910156`, 
    860.0018310546875`}, {263.71783447265625`, 
    637.33642578125`}, {886.817626953125`, 
    305.4976806640625`}, {366.3626403808594`, 382.657470703125`}};
nv = V[[Last[FindShortestTour[V]]]];
mr1 = Polygon@nv;
hole = mr1;
R2 = Disk[#, 510] & /@ V;
Graphics[{Blue, {PointSize[0.02], Point[nv]}, {Opacity[0.2], 
   EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[Red], R2}}]
hole2 = mr1;
For[j = 1, j < Length[nv], j++,
  hole2 = RegionDifference[hole2, R2[[j]]];

  ];

m = DiscretizeRegion[hole2]
Area[m]
```

Comment: Can you post some code to start with?

Comment: Updated with the code

Comment: Also, How to check whether the function RegionDifference[] return empty region

Comment: `reg = Region@RegionUnion[Polygon[Sort@RandomReal[{-1,1},{4,2}]],Polygon[RandomReal[{1,2},{3,2}]]];
bdr=BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg, {{-3,3}, {-3,3}}];
Cases[bdr["Show"], Polygon[x_]:>Length[x], Infinity]`?

Comment: Seem doesnt work for region in my case. It returns 1

Comment: Your code takes a long time to run, I did not wait for it to finish.  A simpler example would be `DiscretizeRegion@
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1.1]]`, which has 4 connected components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ConnectedMeshComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedMeshComponents.html) returns a list of the connected regions, and you can count them using [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html).

Here is a simple example with 4 components,

```
DiscretizeRegion@
 RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1.1]]
```

[image]

```
ConnectedMeshComponents@%
```

[image]

```
Length@%
(* 4 *)
```

The second question,

> How to check whether the function RegionDifference[] return empty region

For simple examples, `RegionDifference` returns `EmptyRegion` directly

```
RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9], 
 Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]
(* EmptyRegion[2] *)
```

If `RegionDifference` returns a `BooleanRegion` instead, you could check using [`RegionEqual`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
reg = RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, 2], Disk[{5, 0}, 2], Disk[{2.5, -4}, 2]];
Region[reg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We now discretize this region using the FEM package. Then we use the element connectivity data that meshes created with the FEM package have and use that to create a connectivity graph. The number of connected regions can then be computed as the number of connected components in the graph.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
connectivity = First[mesh["ElementConnectivity"]];
rules = DeleteCases[{0, _} | {_, 0}]@Flatten[MapIndexed[{First[#2], #} &, connectivity, {2}], 1];
sa = SparseArray[rules -> 1];
Length@ConnectedComponents@AdjacencyGraph[sa]
```

> `3`